# How to get German QWERTY on Windows?

Tags: windows, qwerty, german

Well I'm used to having the world standard keyboard which is qwerty and not `qwertz`... But on Windows I can't find the choice for German input which would be qwerty, not `qwertz`. In Linux there was German input with qwerty so it was fun. I believe it should be on Windows too? Cause i'm sick of this qwertz always having to correct and search for z or y...

Yeah, I know, if Germans made a mistake, it wasn't loosing WW2...

**Edit**: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, it's not about changing between different language inputs? It's about having all german keys in german input, just the z and y would be in the correct places like all the worlds keyboards use and like the US keyboard uses.

Comment: I already found the solution and would give out a really good answer, if this system would allow me to answer to my own question, but it says my reputation is too low for that and new users may not do that... -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the answers that have been given, but unfortunately by searching everywhere and waiting for answers I couldn't find what I needed, so I came up with this solution - I used The The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator

And created my own very custom layout by modifying the default german layout and switching places of z and y.

In case somebody needs it and doesn't want to go the hard way, I decided to upload them, so here are the links to download and install the keyboard layout:

Edit: updated links.

[mega.nz download link](https://mega.nz/file/QsgxnYYS#RXcf6a59hMuVHgjgD8k5r-723oJWT20Q50JjpWFwqb4)

It will appear as a choice under German input between languages in your language bar. If you just want to use this german layout, just remove all german layouts and install this one. Good luck and have fun using it!

Comment: Well that was my answer: http://superuser.com/a/517585/166863

Comment: @ToDo Not really, your answer wasn't there when I had written that and created that keyboard layout. This site just didn't allow me to post it as an answer for some hours because I don't have reputation, but thanks for helping. I'd rep your answer up as well, but I can't this site doesn't allow me cause I don't have enough reputation, lol, I know... That's just ridiculous in this case...

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 7):

What I usually do is to customise keyboard layouts to my liking: adding characters I use frequently for example.

On Windows it is really simple. Just install [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx), load the existing keyboard you want to modify, then make the changes you want and produce a new keyboard layout.

Answer (score 3):

Just install [KbdKaz 500](http://www.omega-com.pl/kbdkaz.htm) in German layout edition. During installation you can choose QWERTY keys layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a little DE or EN in the lower right corner, where the volumne indicator and various other status icons are. Click on it, and you'll see a menue to choose between the configured language settings.

By default pressing Alt-Shift will toggle between the configured language as well.

If you don't have the icon / short cut you can find it (on windows 7) searching for "Language" or "Region" in the application menu thingy formerly known as start menu.

Comment: That was not what I was asking for. I wasn't asking how to change between the languages, I was asking for: when I change to german input, I want it to have y and z in the correct places, that means not like in the german keyboard but like in the us one where you have y between t and u...

Answer (score 0):

In Windows' **Regional and Language Options** control panel dialog box on the **Languages** tab, you can choose different keyboards. On my Win XP system there are two choices for German, plain `German` and `German (IBM)`. The latter might have the QWERTY layout you want.

[image]

Comment: The German IBM layout is a QWERTZ layout too.

Comment: There must be some difference...have you tried the other choice?

Comment: See http://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/keyboards/kbdgr1.html

Comment: Well, if nothing else you could [Create your own keyboard layout using Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for German QWERTY Keyboard Layout driver for Windows check [this project](http://code.google.com/p/german-qwerty-kbd/) out :)

It's a (yet another ;) "programmer's layout" (same idea as for Polish/Czech Programmer's Keyboard) created by me in M$ Keyboard Layout Creator that allows typing umlauts by AltGr + appropriate Latin letter key combinations (+ some useful symbols as extras). Just share it with community, enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to type umlauts on a keyboard fast, use US-International keyboard layout (LAnguage Bar>Settings>Keyboard). On this layout use Shift+" then type the letter that needs double dots to be added. For caps, don't release Shift+" when typing the letter.