# QWERTZ unknown keyboard layout on HP EliteBook. What should I select in Windows 10 preferences?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I bought a HP EliteBook 8460p second hand and it is provided with a QWERTZ layout, but the special characters look more like a US layout. It is definitely not German layout.

I took a picture of it with also a set of stickers to make it "German".

[image]

What layout is the native one printed on the keyboard? Which one should I select in Windows 10?

It looks like a UK keyboard with Z and Y swapped. I cannot find it in the Windows preferences! Is it there?

Comment: Have you tried a UK keyboard layout? If so what happens if you press Z and Y? Do you get Y and Z? If show just swap the physical keys!

Comment: I use QWERTZ everywhere... I want to keep that. If I cannot find a UK QWERTZ layout, I will swap the keys with AutoHotKeys, but I prefer clean solutions. There is MS keyboard layout editor, but I also prefer ready-solutions. I mean, someone made the keyboard... I hope they didn't invent it! Unless the previous user swapped the physical keys theirself.

Comment: "Unless the previous user swapped the physical keys themself." That's what is was thinking ;)

Answer (score 0):

The QWERTZ or QWERTZU keyboard is a widely used computer and typewriter keyboard layout that is mostly used in Central Europe. The name comes from the first six letters at the top left of the keyboard: Q, W, E, R, T, and Z.

The main difference between QWERTZ and QWERTY is that the positions of the "Z" and "Y" keys are switched, this change being made for two major reasons:

"Z" is a much more common letter than "Y" in German; the latter rarely appears outside words whose spellings reflect either their importation from a foreign language or the Hellenization of an older German form under the influence of Ludwig I of Bavaria.
"T" and "Z" often appear next to each other in the German orthography, and placing the two keys next to each other minimizes the effort needed for typing the two characters in sequence (cf. the use of a single-block tz ligature in many early mechanical printing presses using fraktur typefaces).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ
Also this link has a good how too on changing your keyboard layout.

[How to get german QWERTY on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/517562/how-to-get-german-qwerty-on-windows)

Towards the bottom there's screenshots on how to set it up.

Comment: I know how to set keyboards, I'm asking which layout I actually have. If you open your first link and compare the layouts listed with the photo I provided, you will see that the don't match at all. Only the QWERTZ part is correct, every other symbol is out of place. Look between P and Enter: only one of the QWERTZ keyboards listed give [] which change into {} with the Shift. The Slovak is the closest one, but then the symbols above the numbers don't match.