# Laptop with an unknown keyboard layout

Tags: laptop, keyboard-layout, qwerty

Does anyone recognise this keyboard layout? It looks like a cross between Swedish (because of the capital O-uml and A-uml) and German (because of the positions of the hash etc)? I cannot find a named keyboard that matches it!

Is it a cross of a Swedish and German keyboard but with a QWERTY (not QWERTZ) layout? If it has a name, I and some others would be grateful to hear!

[image: keyboard photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text I can see on the keys is in German.
I worked in Germany for two year and got to know the keyboard quite well. However as you say the position of the Y and Z are not in the usual German positions.

Comment: this is what I mean - there is no option in windows 10 that matches this physical layout?!

Comment: @alle_meije Try an answer from [How to get german QWERTY on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/517562)

Comment: Brilliant! It's not "official" I guess but with the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator it can be fixed. I loaded the German key mappings, swapped the y and z (and Y and Z) around and it seems to do the trick! Still not much use for the ö and the ä but it's very nice that it gives the letters on the actual keys :)